# Blackberry can't stop audio when setLoopCount(-1);

Tags: java, blackberry, media-player, infinite

I have the following code:

```
InputStream stream = (InputStream)this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/preview.mp3");
            Player p = Manager.createPlayer(stream, "audio/mpeg");
            p.realize();
            p.prefetch();
            p.setLoopCount(-1);
            VolumeControl volume = (VolumeControl) p.getControl("VolumeControl");
            volume.setLevel(1);
            p.start();
```

Then when I call stopAlarm()

```
// Stop playing music
    void stopAlarm()
    {
        try
        {
            // Tell player to stop playing
            p.stop();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Dialog.alert("Error stopping music");
        }

        // Then release the data and close out the player
        p.deallocate();
        p.close();
    }
```

In short, it doesn't stop the audio.

I would be very grateful if someone could help me out on this one.

Comment: Are you getting any error messages or exceptions thrown?

Comment: Does it happens if you set loop count to a big number, like `setLoopCount(10000)`? If so, it may not be related to the -1 value.

Comment: As far as I can see, it happens if you use setLoopCount(); no matter what value you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Vivek, I noticed a very small mistake which prevented this from working. As always, it was extremely simple.

Although Player was defined as a Class level variable:

```
static Player p;
```

the problem was of course the following, causing a conflict:

```
Player p = Manager.createPlayer(stream, "audio/mpeg");
```

So now the code is:

```
InputStream stream = (InputStream)this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/preview.mp3");
p = Manager.createPlayer(stream, "audio/mpeg");
p.realize();
p.prefetch();
p.setLoopCount(-1);
VolumeControl volume = (VolumeControl) p.getControl("VolumeControl");
volume.setLevel(1);
p.start();
```

Of course to stop it, I simply used:

```
p.stop();
p.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
// Stop playing music
void stopAlarm() {
    try {
        p.stop();
        Thread.sleep(50);
        p.close();
        Thread.sleep(50);
        p.deallocate();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Dialog.alert("Error stopping music");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

first check player object 'p' is null or not before stopping the player.

like

```
if(p != null)
{
    p.stop();
}
else
{
  Dialog.alert("p is null"); //to identify player is null or not.
}
```

if player object is null then i guess you are creating the player object as a local.

so create player object like

```
p = Manager.createPlayer(stream, "audio/mpeg");
```

and define the class level player variable.

Comment: Yes, the Player has been declared as a Class level variable. I didn't think of making sure whether the Player object was null or not, it could very well be the case...